# Not adding Values within loop VB.NET

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

this is my first time posting on here :)
I am coding a program that will look through various lines and subtract the difference of the time each line was added (each line has a timestamp) and I've successfully converted the timestamps into seconds and added them to the array int32 time(). What I want to do next is make a loop that has the values (82467, 82493, 82518, 82544).(time) Does anyone know how to make a loop that runs through them and gets the difference of for example time(3) - time(2) (then adds this value to the location of an array), next loop does time(2) - time(1)(storing in another location in the array), then time(1) - time(0)(storing that, too). and then calculates the mean values of the stored values? Because when I do my code, which is this loop:

```
    Dim b As Integer = time.Length - 1

    While b > 0
        DataTextBox.Text += b.ToString

        calculation += time(b) - time(b - 1)
        MessageBox.Show(calculation)

        b -= 1
    End While
```

I get this output:
82467
which is the value of time(0).

Thank you very much in advance, and if I did anything wrong in the way I asked for help, please let me know so I can do it in a better way next time. Thank you!

Comment: after this code, the code to do the mean would be calculation = calculation / DataTextBox.Lines.Length  DataTextBox.Text += "    " + calculation.ToString

Answer (score 0):

You could use a For loop

```
calculation = 0

For b As Integer = time.Length-1 To 1 Step -1
    DataTextBox.Text += b.ToString

    calculation += time(b) - time(b - 1)
    MessageBox.Show(calculation)
Next
```